# SqlDataReader and API

Tags: c#, parameters, sqldatareader

```
private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        object functionReturnValue = null;

        using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection parameter = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            string url = "My API";

            connection.Open();

            command = new SqlCommand("Select  Column1 From Table1", connection);

            datareader = command.ExecuteReader();
           
            while (datareader.Read())
            {
                string Column = datareader["Column1"].ToString();
                parameter.Add("1", Column.ToString());//target numbers
                parameter.Add("2", TextBox.Text);//message
                parameter.Add("3", "Username");
                parameter.Add("passwd", "Password");

                dynamic rpb = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", parameter);

                functionReturnValue = (new System.Text.UTF8Encoding()).GetString(rpb);
            }

            datareader.Close();
            connection.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Message is sent!.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
}
```

I'm working with a `SqlDatareader` to retrieve data from my column in my database which contains numbers where I want to send my textmessage from a textbox, the problem is that my datareader only reads the first content in the column where I contain my numbers and only sends a single message, instead of sending the messages from the textbox to all the numbers in `Column1`. Please help.

Comment: Try debugging by putting breakpoints and see what values you are getting from the database.

Comment: From : "Select  Column1 From Table1"  To : "Select  * From Table1"

Comment: @jdweng i get an error when i include * System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'Column1'.', i only want to read column1 not all the columns in table1

Comment: Why are you getting a period when I posted an asterisk?  If you are only getting one value then there is only one value in the column and the other values are in other columns.

Comment: @jdweng i currently have 4 numbers in column1 its stops in the first value of column

Comment: How is column defined in the database?

Comment: @jdweng column1 is named Faculty and its data type is text.

Comment: Is it possible the are returns in the data and the other columns are on new lines?

Comment: You're overwriting the `parameter` N/V pairs on each loop of the `while`. Side point: you must dispose your connection, command and reader properly with `using`. Do *not* cache the connection object

Comment: @Charlieface how am i going to do that?

Comment: Well what do you want to happen? How do you propose to pass a N/V collection of multiple rows, if every row has the same names?

Comment: Sorry im quite a beginner @Charlieface what does N/V means, i want to send the messages to the numbers that i have in my column1 individually, what code do i use in order to achieve it?

Comment: You have a variable `NameValueCollection parameter` which you are adding things to, but on each run of the loop you are adding `parameter.Add("1", Column.ToString());` etc which means that you are overwriting the previous values. You need a new name for each value you are adding. Perhaps you can use a counter variable, and do something like `counter++; parameter.Add("1_" + counter, Column.ToString());`

Comment: @Charlieface I've used the counter method but i didnt work.

Comment: "but it didn't work" means what exactly? Please show your current code

Comment: while (dr.Read()){string FirstYear = dr["Column"].ToString(); counter++;  parameter.Add("1"+counter,Column.ToString());
 parameter.Add("2", richTextBox1.Text);//message
                    parameter.Add("3", "...");
                    parameter.Add("passwd", "u$hg4gi&w&");
                    dynamic rpb = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", parameter);
                    functionReturnValue = (new System.Text.UTF8Encoding()).GetString(rpb);
           I want to solve this as but im too noob i've tried but up until now i still cant solve it, @Charlieface, thank you are a hero to me.

Comment: You are only using `+ counter` on the first value. Does this not add at least that firsy value for each row?

Comment: No, instead of sending a message to the very first number in the column it stopped sending.

Comment: @Charlieface how to solve this?